# Simple .NET Core Web Application Template fails

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Have just updated VS2015 (update 3) to the 2.0.1 version of .NET Core tools. Now if I do:
 File->New Project->.NET Core->ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) 
and then select the "Empty" project, I see errors as soon as the package restore phase begins (219 errors indeed) with red squigglies all over the project.json file. The situation is worse with the more sophisticated templates, so either something's badly broken or I'm doing something wrong. I hope the latter, but can anyone confirm this simple process works for them?

EDIT: The first few Package Manager errors below:

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "E:\MikeP\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication3\.vs\restore.dg"
log  : Restoring packages for E:\MikeP\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication3\src\WebApplication3\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in E:\MikeP\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication3\src\WebApplication3\project.json...
error: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
error: Package Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils 1.0.0 supports:
error:   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
error: Package System.Diagnostics.Process 4.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package System.Diagnostics.Process 4.1.0 supports:
error:   - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
error:   - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
error:   - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
error:   - netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4)
```

Comment: You should show an example of the errors in your question.

Comment: Check the output window, if nuget logs some errors. If so, please add them to your post.